# Setting color in constant's file variable in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

This is my Constants file in cocoa.

```
  #ifndef confEx__CHBConstants_h
   #define confEx__CHBConstants_h


   #define invalidUserStatus @"Invalid"
   #define serverProblemStatus @"Server problem"
    #define appleIdRequiredStatus @"check"

  #endif
```

Is there a way to set a color for the variable, for instance (serverProblemStatus), in this file itself?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the syntax coloring of Xcode: No there's no way to change source code colors from within code.

Side note: Your defines are preprocessor macros, not variables—and they deserve to be brown ;)